# Header Formatting Avoiding Cells With Text for Multiple Dataframes to_excel() Output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, header, export-to-excel

I have a program which outputs a certain amount of dataframes to excel, one dataframe per one sheet in the excel workbook. I want to use header formatting for this, especially for the wrap text = true, because it is really annoying to expand like 30 cells on 15 sheets just to see the names.

For some reason, my header formatting seems to work, but it only works on cells that do not have any text/data in them. This, of course, is useless. Here is a screenshot of the output I get: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiEdD.png)

Here is the code I am using for this:

```
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('avad7.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'text_wrap': True,
    'valign': 'top',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'border': 1})

i = 0

for qw, x in ewm_pivot.groupby(ewm_pivot.isnull().dot(ewm_pivot.columns)):
    # print(x.dropna(1))
    x = x.dropna(1)
    x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet' + str(i))
    worksheet = writer.sheets['sheet' + str(i)]
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, header_format)
    worksheet.set_row(1, None, header_format)
    i += 1

writer.save()
```

Any solutions would be appreciated :)

Comment: The reason this happens, and the way to deal with it, is explained in the XlsxWriter docs: [Formatting of the Dataframe headers](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers)

Comment: @jmcnamara Hey, thanks for responding. I originally used that website as a reference to create the code above. (the header_format variable is an exact copy while I get it to work haha). I still do not understand what the problem is. The only cells getting formatted are the ones where nothing is inside (see screenshot).

Comment: You are missing the most important parts of the linked example: omitting the Pandas generated index and creating your own in a for() loop. Run the linked example and then tailor it to your DataFrame.